# shell script to give users sudo access

Tags: bash

Give sudo access to users via shell script. I want to create a shell script to give users sudo access and add them to sudoers file. So far I have got this below. I am new to programming

Inputs:

- `$ROOT_USERS` - An array of users to add to the root sudoers policy

Add users:

```
rootUsers=(${ROOT_USERS//,/ })

for rootUser in "${rootUsers[@]}"; do
  echo "Adding user, $rootUser"
  useradd $user
  echo "s0m3Pw0rdz!" | passwd --stdin $user 
done

echo 'Completed Successfully'
```

Comment: How do you know if the script "Completed Successfully"? You aren't testing the result of either the `useradd` or the `passwd` command. And what part of your sample code is related to sudo? Can you expand on your strategy here, and explain how you *think* this should work?

Answer (score 3):

Don't have your script modify `sudoers`. This is messy and fragile.

Instead, create a new group for your "root users" with `groupadd rootusers`, and add a `sudoers` rule that gives them all access:

```
%rootusers   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Now your script can simply add new users to that group:

```
useradd -G rootusers "$user"
```

---

Here's your script with this change and a few other bugs fixed:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Example input
ROOT_USERS="foo,bar"

rootUsers=(${ROOT_USERS//,/ })

for user in "${rootUsers[@]}"; do
  echo "Adding user, $user"
  useradd -G rootusers $user
  echo "s0m3Pw0rdz!" | passwd --stdin $user
done

echo 'Completed Successfully'
```

Again, this depends on you having manually added `%rootusers   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` in sudoers as a one-time thing first.

Comment: @user8185098 With this approach, you can keep using your script and just add `-G rootusers` to give the new user sudo access

Comment: can i reachout to you via hangouts ?

Comment: No, but SO will allow converting comment chains to chat when they get long

Comment: does this looks correct

# Inputs:
# $ROOT_USERS - An array of users to add to the root sudoers policy

#Add users
rootUsers=(${ROOT_USERS//,/ })

for rootUser in "${rootUsers[@]}"; do
  echo "Adding user, $rootUser -G rootusers"
  useradd $user
  echo "s0m3Pw0rdz!" | passwd --stdin $user 
done

echo 'Completed Successfully'


#Update sudoers flie
sed -i '1 i\#' /etc/sudoers

cat >> /etc/sudoers << EOF
%wheel        ALL=(ALL)       ALL
EOF

Comment: No. Your script should not modify `sudoers`. You should do that once, manually, so that your script doesn't have to deal with it.

Comment: is there a reason behind it ..just curious

Comment: @user8185098 The main reason is that if your script adds an invalid line to sudoers, maybe just by adding a user whose name is `Defaults` or other name special to sudo, you will lock yourself and everyone else out of the system.

Comment: alrighty thanks for your explanation sorry i am new to scripting on the path of learning, so this below should give users sudo access ?

# Inputs:
# $ROOT_USERS - An array of users to add to the root sudoers policy

#Add users
rootUsers=(${ROOT_USERS//,/ })

for rootUser in "${rootUsers[@]}"; do
  echo "Adding user, $rootUser -G rootusers"
  useradd $user
  echo "s0m3Pw0rdz!" | passwd --stdin $user 
done

echo 'Completed Successfully'

Comment: You just added `-G rootusers` to the `echo` statement, so it will only be written to screen and not used to add the user to a group. I've updated the answer with a complete script

Comment: Gaaa, lack of formatting is making my eyes bleed! @user8185098, if you need to expand your question with formatted text in order to make the question more clear, please just [**edit the question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50472279/edit).

Comment: i want to check the first line of the script and if the first line is a # the script should not run i came up with this not sure if its the right syntax and login

p=`cat -n1 /tmp/abc | awk '{print $1}`
if [ $p = "#" ]; then
exit 0
fi

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to add users to suders list by passing the list of users as command line argument

```
#!/bin/bash
#addSudoUsers.sh

while [[ -n $1 ]]; do
    echo "$1    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers;
    shift # shift all parameters;
done
```

You can run this script as `sudo ./addSudoUsers.sh user1 user2 user3`

Comment: The downside to this approach is that if you add if you try to add a user named "my name" or "Defaults" or anything else that `sudo` has an issue with, it will cause `sudoers` to be invalid. `sudo` will then be locked for all users, so you can't just `sudo visudo` to fix it.